# I'm trying to output a specific product using associative array

Tags: php

I want to access a specific value in my array, using an associative array. But I'm definitely getting something wrong.

I want to output Tablet in the products array.

```
<?php

$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$new = [];
$numbers = $new;
$products = [1 => 'Mobile phone', 2 => 'Smart watch', 3 => 'Laptop', 4 => 'Headphones', 5 => 'Tablet'];

if ($numbers) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($numbers); $i++) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
    }
} elseif ($numbers !== $new) {
    for ($i =0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
    }
} else {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo $product[5];
        echo '<br />';
    }
}

?>
```

I'm not sure how to include this as a code.

The output on the browser is:

[image: Output of the code on the browser]

PS. I'm just starting off.

Comment: Cause your `if statement` goes into `else` condition and your `foreach loop` prints the 6-th letter of each element.

Comment: If you want to print `Tablet`, that should be `echo $products[5];` without the loop.

Comment: Why do you do `$numbers = $new;`? What was the point of initializing `$number` if you're just going to replace it 2 lines later?

Comment: @Barmar I was just trying to set conditions that'll activate the loop. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: but if you intend to loop over `$numbers`, you shouldn't set it to an empty array.